# Square iOS Web API returns amount_invalid_format error with any amount contains 0.99

Tags: square, square-connect

I'm using Square Point of Sale transaction using Square iOS Web API from my iOS application. I'm getting amount_invalid_format error when I pass any amount with 0.99 for example 1.99, 20.99, or so on.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs whenever you try to charge with an amount that is not an integer value, such as a decimal or a floating point number. One thing you can do to prevent this is to check and make sure the type of amount you're charging is a integer.

Answer (score 0):

This unit of amount is cent. So you need to pass a value 99 instead of 0.99.